# Replacing values in one pandas dataframe with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have to replace values from one dataframe with values from another dataframe.

Example bellow works, but I have extra steps in order to replace values in "first" column with values from "new" column and than drop "new" column.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                  

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'X'], 
   ...:                    ['B', 'X'], 
   ...:                    ['C', 'X'], 
   ...:                    ['A', 'Y'], 
   ...:                    ['B', 'Y'], 
   ...:                    ['C', 'Y'], 
   ...:                    ], columns=['first', 'second'])                                                                   

In [3]: df                                                                                                                   
Out[3]: 
  first second
0     A      X
1     B      X
2     C      X
3     A      Y
4     B      Y
5     C      Y

In [4]: df_tt = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'E'], 
   ...:                       ['B', 'F'], 
   ...:                      ], columns=['orig', 'new'])                                                                     

In [5]: df_tt                                                                                                                
Out[5]: 
  orig new
0    A   E
1    B   F

In [6]: df = df.merge(df_tt, left_on='first', right_on='orig')                                                               

In [7]: df                                                                                                                   
Out[7]: 
  first second orig new
0     A      X    A   E
1     A      Y    A   E
2     B      X    B   F
3     B      Y    B   F

In [8]: df['first'] = df['new']                                                                                              

In [9]: df                                                                                                                   
Out[9]: 
  first second orig new
0     E      X    A   E
1     E      Y    A   E
2     F      X    B   F
3     F      Y    B   F

In [10]: df.drop(columns=['orig', 'new'])                                                                                    
Out[10]: 
  first second
0     E      X
1     E      Y
2     F      X
3     F      Y
```

I would like to replace values with no extra steps.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is using [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
# Restrict to common entries
df = df[df['first'].isin(df_tt['orig'])]

# Use df_tt as a mapping to replace values in df

df['first'] = df['first'].replace(df_tt.set_index('orig').to_dict()['new'])
```

Solution very similar to @jezrael, but I like the idea of explicitly using `replace`, because this is actually what you are doing: replacing values in one dataframe based on another dataframe.

Comment: Your soulution as well as jezrael's is good. Thanks guys.
Actually your solution works without "to_dict" too: 
df['first'] = df['first'].replace(df_tt.set_index('orig')['new'])

Answer (score 2):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for filtering with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = (df[df['first'].isin(df_tt['orig'])]
         .assign(first=lambda x: x['first'].map(df_tt.set_index('orig')['new'])))
print (df)
  first second
0     E      X
1     F      X
3     E      Y
4     F      Y
```

Alternative:

```
df = df[df['first'].isin(df_tt['orig'])]
df['first'] = df['first'].map(df_tt.set_index('orig')['new'])
```

Comment: Is it as fast as merge? Merge is quite fast.

Comment: @user3225309 - It is faster, the best test it with real data